# Read name and value from every define('NAME','VALUE'); inside a .php file

Tags: php, file, parsing

I'm implementing a php interface to process a .php file containing a bunch of define sentences defining constants with text values to translate by somebody.

The input is parsed sentence by sentence and shown in the interface to the translator who will input the translation in a html textarea and send it to the server

By the end of the process an output file would be generated, identical to the input .php file, only with the define values translated.

E.g. processing an input file 'eng.php' like this:

```
<?php
define ("SENTENCE_1", "A sentence to translate");
?>
```

would give the translated output file 'spa.php' like this:

```
<?php
define ("SENTENCE_1", "The same sentence translated to spanish");
?>
```

For this I would like to know:

1. What is the best way to parse the input file to get the constant names and values in an array? (Something like `$var[0]['name']` would be "SENTENCE_1" and `$var[0]['value']` would be "A sentence to translate")
2. Would it be possible to get the translation from google translator shown in the input textarea as a suggestion to edit for the person who is translating it? How? (I read google translator api v1 is no longer available and v2 is only available as a paid service. Are there any free alternatives?)

Comment: Why you don't use an array? So many constants takes a lot of memory.

Comment: The reason I'm not using an array is they're constants, meaning their value doesn't change since they're first assigned. That seemed a legit reason to declare them with define...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/es/function.get-defined-constants.php

What about that?

Comment: I give you the answer for being the fastest and as useful as the rest (who also were pretty fast and have my gratitude), but my answer completes yours (Specially since nobody said anything about point '2' of my question). Thanks

Answer (score 2):

[get_defined_constants](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-constants.php) doesn't give you exactly the structure you asked for, but it should be sufficient.

```
define('MY_CONSTANT', 'something');
define('MY_CONSTANT_2', 'another');

$constants = get_defined_constants(true);
$constants = $constants['user'];

print_r($constants); 
/**
 * array(
 *  'MY_CONSTANT' => 'something',
 *  'MY_CONSTANT_2' => 'another'
 * )
 */
```

Note that this will be all constants defined in the current scope, which in PHP is gonna be anything defined this request.

Answer (score 1):

Use [get_defined_constants()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-constants.php) to get the list of all the defined constants.

To get userdefined constant specially

```
$allconstants = get_defined_constants(true);
print_r($allconstants['user']);
```

Answer (score 1):

In case anybody needs to read constants' names and values defined in a given .php file into an array of variables without actually defining those constants (E.g. if some different constant with the same name was previously defined, thus giving an error when processing the file with `include` or `require`), here is how I did it (Warning: I haven't had any trouble yet, but it's not thoroughly tested, so it can be buggy).

```
if (file_exists($filename)){
    $outf=fopen($filename,'r');
    while (($line=fgets($outf))!==false){
        if (strpos($line, 'define')!==false){
            $parts=explode("\"",implode("\"",explode("'",implode("\\q",explode("\\\"",implode("\\s",explode("\\'",$line)))))));
            $name=implode("\\'",explode("\\s",implode("\\\"",explode("\\q",$parts[1]))));
            $value=implode("\\'",explode("\\s",implode("\\\"",explode("\\q",$parts[3]))));
            $outconstants[$name]=$value;
        }
    }
}
```

You can see I assume there's no more than 1 `define` sentence per line, and that the names and values of the constants are specified as string values using PHP notation (between single (') or double (") quotes.)

Also, escaped quotes (\" or \') are temporarily escaped as \q (\") or \s (\') instead, to properly match the non-escaped ones, and then escaped back as usual once what's in between the non escaped ones is assigned to $name and $value.

The google api problem was solved using microsoft translation api instead (free up to 2.000.000 chars/month): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff512421.aspx#phpexample

Comment: Oh gawd. Don't use frigging explode to split up strings the cumbersome way. Use a regex and do some assertions while you're at it. More concise, more precise.

Comment: I know. But regex hate me,and I didn't want to spend the rest of the night figuring out why ^^'